# LS paths construction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $W$ be the Weyl group of a simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak L$, and for a dominant weight $\lambda$ denote by $W_{\lambda}$ the stabilizer of $\lambda$ in $W$. Let $\leq$ be the Bruhat order on $W/W_{\lambda}$. A pair $\pi = (\underline{\tau} , \underline{a})$ of sequences ( $\underline{\tau}: \tau_0 > \tau_1 > \tau_2 > \ldots > \tau_r$ a sequence of cosets on $W/W_{\lambda}$ and $\underline{a}: a_0 :=0 <a_1 <a_2 < \ldots <a_r < a_{r+1}:=1$ is a sequence of rational numbers) is called a LS path of shape $\lambda$ if the following condition satisfied:

For all $i=1, \ldots r$ set $m_i=l(\tau_{i-1})-l(\tau_i)$. There exists a sequence $\beta_1, \beta_2 \cdots \beta_{m_i}$ of positive roots joining $\tau_i$ and $\tau_{i-1}$ by the corresponding reflections, i.e.,

$\tau_{i-1} > s_{\beta_1}\tau_{i-1} > s_{\beta_2}s_{\beta_1}\tau_{i-1} > \ldots > s_{\beta_{m_i}} \cdots s_{\beta_2}s_{\beta_1}\tau_{i-1}=\tau_i$ with $a_i \langle s_{\beta_{j-1}} \cdots s_{\beta_2}s_{\beta_1}\tau_{i-1}(\lambda), \check{\beta_j} \rangle \in \mathbb Z$ for all $j=1, \ldots m_i$.

We say that $\pi$ is standard on a Bruhat interval $[v,w]$ if $w \geq \tau_0$ and $\tau_r \geq v$.

Given $\lambda$, $w$ and $v$, I am having a tough time computing all standard LS paths on $[v,w]$. I have the following questions.

1. Let $\mathfrak L$ is of type $A_4$ and $\lambda=3\alpha_1+6\alpha_2+4\alpha_3+2\alpha_4$. Take $w=s_2s_1s_4s_3s_2$ and $v=s_2$. In this case what are all standard LS paths on $[v,w]$ ?
2. For each LS path above is there an easier way to construct a path vector or a standard monomial without going through the Littelmann's construction (that uses quantum groups).

Comment: Your notation is confusing, since the $\alpha_i$ are usually taken to be simple roots.   For $\lambda$ to be dominant, it must be a non-negative integral combination of fundamental weights $\varpi_i$.  Where does your $\lambda$ come from?

Comment: The $\alpha_i$'s are the simple roots and here $\lambda= 5\omega_2$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the notation.   By the way, the representation here is fairly large, so computations tend to get long if done by hand.   I don't see an easy way to approach your example.   (Combinatorists might be helpful.  Maybe add tags 'co.combinatorics' and 'rt.representation-theory'?  The last two tags are less useful here.)